# Error SML NJ-Operator and Operand don't agree

Tags: ml

When I try to compile my ML Program ,I get an error saying:"Operator and Operand don't agree".

```
candidates.sml:78.8-78.40 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
operator domain: int * (int * 'Z * 'Y) list
operand:         int * (int * real) list
in expression:
tr (n,candidates)
```

I understand the error but I can't find a solution.
The part of the code where I get the error is:

```
 fun agonas fileName = 
    let 
        fun tr(n,[])=[]
        |   tr(n,((a,b,c)::d))=((n-a+1),b,c)::(tr(n,d))
        val (n,l,candidates) = parse fileName
        val cand = tr(n,candidates)
    in
        my_solution(l,cand)
  end;
```

,where the candidates are related with the part below:

```
fun parse file =
let
(* a function to read an integer from an input stream *)
    fun next_int input =
    Option.valOf (TextIO.scanStream (Int.scan StringCvt.DEC) input)
(* a function to read a real that spans till the end of line *)
    fun next_real input =
    Option.valOf (TextIO.inputLine input)
(* open input file and read the two integers in the first line *)
    val stream = TextIO.openIn file
    val n = next_int stream
    val l = next_int stream
val _ = TextIO.inputLine stream
(* a function to read the pair of integer & real in subsequent lines *)
    fun scanner 0 acc = acc
      | scanner i acc =
        let
            val d = next_int stream
            val (SOME v) = Real.fromString (next_real stream)
        in
            scanner (i - 1) ((d, v) :: acc)
        end
in
    (n, l,  rev(scanner n []))
end;

fun my_solution ( n , l ,candidates ) = [2 ,3 ,5 ,4 ,6]
fun agonas fileName = my_solution ( parse fileName )
```

I would appreciate it if you could find the mistake.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `parse`, using `scanner`, builds a list of pairs — `(int * real) list` —  while `tr` expects to get a list of triples — `(int * 'Z * 'Y) list`.

Not knowing what `tr` is supposed to do, the quick and dirty fix would be to change

```
tr(n,((a,b,c)::d))=((n-a+1),b,c)::(tr(n,d))
```

into

```
tr(n,((a,b)::d))=((n-a+1),b)::(tr(n,d))
```

But that may be the wrong solution - it depends on what the code is supposed to do.

(Sometimes it helps to explicitly write out the types yourself - even before writing the code - instead of relying on type inference to catch the places where you need to do some more thinking.)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: the offending line calls `trans`, and that is a function that expects two arguments, the second being a list of *triples*. However, you are passing it a list of *pairs* instead (as produced by your `scanner` function).

You didn't show us the `trans` function, so I cannot be more specific about what the appropriate fix would be.

Comment: Sorry,function tr is the same with function trans.I edited it now.Can you see the mistake?Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well, the mistake is what I already described: your `parse`/`scanner` function and your `tr` function don't agree about the structure of the `candidates` list. It is hard to say how to fix it without knowing what this code is trying to achieve. But for starters, you could just try to drop the `c` component from the tuple in function `tr`.